# best way to move/copy string in async operation?

Tags: c++, string, boost-asio, move-semantics

Considering the following example, which is the best way to move/copy/capture a string for async operations? is passing as & in the Session a good idea?

```
void Client::connect(const std::string& hostname, const std::string& port, const std::string& string) {
  auto socket_ = std::make_shared<net::ip::tcp::socket>(_io_context);
  net::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_(_io_context);
  auto endpoints_ = resolver_.resolve(hostname, port);

  net::async_connect(*socket_, endpoints_, [socket_, string](sys::error_code ec, net::ip::tcp::endpoint) {
    if(!ec) {
      std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(*socket_), std::move(string))->start();
    }
  });
}

Session::Session(net::ip::tcp::socket socket, const std::string& string)
  : _socket(std::move(socket)), _string(std::move(string)) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just passing the string by value and moving it around is both clean and efficient.

```
void Client::connect(const std::string& hostname, const std::string& port, std::string string) {
  auto socket_ = std::make_shared<net::ip::tcp::socket>(_io_context);
  net::ip::tcp::resolver resolver_(_io_context);
  auto endpoints_ = resolver_.resolve(hostname, port);

  net::async_connect(*socket_, endpoints_, [socket_, string{std::move(string)}](sys::error_code ec, net::ip::tcp::endpoint) mutable {
    if(!ec) {
      std::make_shared<Session>(std::move(*socket_), std::move(string))->start();
    }
  });
}

Session::Session(net::ip::tcp::socket socket, std::string string)
  : _socket(std::move(socket)), _string(std::move(string)) {

}
```

Take particular note of the syntax in the lambda capture that allows for moving an object into the lambda.

Comment: So the assumption is correct that if I pass it as & in the Session Constructor add addition work, so on runtime there is a addition conversion from string to & and then dereference? lets say the _string member is also a const std::string _string?

Comment: @newbie, No, that has no impact in any material way. What changes is that by accepting a `const std::string&`, you make it so that there has to be two string objects, a read-only source one that you read from, and a destination `_string` object that you copy to. By taking the string by value, and **moving** from the source to the destination, you can avoid having to create a copy of the string data.

Comment: And what if I am not using the string as member instead using it to initalize diffrent members like:
_file(std::move(string), std::ifstream::in | std::fstream::binary), file_size(std::filesystem::file_size(std::move(string)))

Comment: @newbie, in that case, yes, if nothing is taking ownership of the string, then you should accept it by constant reference (and also not move it when calling Session's constructor)